# laravel command handle function dependency injection

Tags: laravel

I have created a very basic command in a lavarel webapp:

```
$ php artisan make:command MyCommand
```

I need to access a repository in handle function.

A repository class is basically a static class for me.

I have read some tutorials and i have read i need to add my repository as an argument to handle function this way:

```
public function handle(MyRepository $repo)
{
    ...
}
```

It works !

My question is why is it working ?
How can php guess to call handle function with this parameter ?

Is it dependency injection ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Laravel knows to resolve dependencies because it calls the method via its container, rather than directly: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/862c4529edfce579bf7746797b7f95e4aed304a0/src/Illuminate/Bus/Dispatcher.php#L94

It’s well worth diving into the framework source code if you’re curious how something works.

Comment: Thanks but why this is working while i do not have registred the MyRepository somewhere (as a provider for example)

Comment: If Laravel can resolve a class, it will. So if you’ve type-hinted `MyRepository` and Laravel can construct it, then it’ll get injected. It doesn’t need to be explicitly registered in the container, although you can do so if you want to bind a repository implementation to an interface for example.